# Python selenium: use while true/false to continue running script when element not present

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I wrote a selenium script to continue running if a certain condition is not met. Such as:

```
condition = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.S_txt1').is_displayed()
while not condition:
   run this
```

I would get this message if I run the code:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.S_txt1"}
```

I found a workaround by using:

```
condition = []
while condition == []:
   condition = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.S_txt1')
   run this
```

so that if the element is not found then the list will still be empty, the code will continue running.

But I'd still like to know how to do it the True / False way. Is there anyway that this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
if driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.S_txt1').is_displayed():
    run this
else:
    run that
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of the elements if more than 0

```
if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.S_txt1'))>0 :
   print("elements found")
   //your statement
else:
   print("No such element")
   //your statement
```

---

Or try..except block

```
try:
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.S_txt1')
   print("element found")
   //your statement
except:
   pass
   print("No such element")
   //your statement
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said you can check the size of the elements returned:

```
while condition == driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.S_txt1') > 0:
    run this
```

You could also use ExpectedConditions:
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits

presence_of_element_located